# how to get last row that has velue Excel VBA within a range

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA Macro. i just want to know how to get the last row that has value within a range

```
 Set MyRange = Worksheets(strSheet).Range(strColumn & "1")
GetLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, MyRange.Column).End(xlUp).Row
```

this code could find the last row for the whole sheet.. i just want it to find the last non null value cells
(
like in this case in the picture.. for the ("A8") range, the last row result should be ("A9:B9")

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`"A9:B9"` cannot be last row... It is a range.

If you need such a range, but based on the last empty row, starting from a specific cell, you can use the next approach:

```
Sub testLastRowRange()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, myRange As Range, lastRow As Long, strColumn As String
   Dim lastCol As Long, endingRowRng As Range, strSheet As String
   
   strSheet = ActiveSheet.Name 'please, use here your real sheet name
   Set sh = Worksheets(strSheet)
   strColumn = "A"
   Set myRange = sh.Range(strColumn & 8)
   lastRow = myRange.End(xlDown).row
   lastCol = myRange.End(xlToRight).Column
   Set endingRowRng = sh.Range(sh.Cells(lastRow, myRange.Column), sh.Cells(lastRow, lastCol))
   Debug.Print endingRowRng.address
End Sub
```

Comment: @Yusuf Rahmaniac: Did you find time to check the received answers code?

Answer (score 0):

For your specific example you could use `CurrentRegion` property.

This is based on the `ActiveCell` which is not generally advisable.

```
Sub x()

Dim r As Range

Set r = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion

MsgBox r.Address

End Sub
```